# How do I group emails with same subject and sender in the Outlook app on Android?

Tags: outlook

How do I group emails by subject in the Outlook app on Android?

In Gmail, if 100 emails are received from the same address and have the same subject, they are grouped into a single item with a number in parenthesis showing how many emails are inside.

How do I achieve the equivalent in Android Outlook app? Or web app? Otherwise, there are 100 elements that fill up the list of unread in the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings, turn on "Organize mail by thread" to ensure responses sent back and forth on the same thread are grouped together.

From what I can tell, there is no setting in the Outlook Android app that will group multiple independent emails with the same sender / subject.